# java.lang.NullPointerException $ExpandableAdapter.getGroupView

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I use a custom `BaseExpandableListAdapter` with `Fragment` Class, but I don't know why i get the `NullPointerException` :

**Code :**

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_list, null); <= NullPointerException
    }

    ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(parentItems.get(groupPosition));
    ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);

    return convertView;
}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at pro.businessbook.fragments.RechercheVilleSecteurFragment$ExpandableAdapter.getGroupView(RechercheVilleSecteurFragment.java:373)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:446)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2232)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1253)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1162)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15775)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4942)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1411)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:698)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15775)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:666)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15775)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4942)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15775)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4942)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15775)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4942)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1411)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:698)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15775)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:704)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15775)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4942)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15775)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:850)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15775)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4942)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2193)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15775)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2212)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1486)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1181)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4942)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5370)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
05-02 13:00:52.219: E/AndroidRuntime(21979):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 13:00:52.278: D/jdwp(21979): processIncoming
05-02 13:00:52.278: D/jdwp(21979): handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xB, len=0x13, id=0x101F, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
```

**group_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView 
        android:id ="@+id/label_indicator"
        android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height ="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id ="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height ="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/label_indicator"/>
    <CheckBox 
        android:id ="@+id/cb"
        android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:focusable="false"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please post the stacktrace? And **indicate the line** of your program that throws the exception.

Comment: also post your `group_list.xml` layout file

Comment: Is `parentItems` initialized properly?

Comment: Read the stack trace. And find some tutorial on basic debugging in Android. [Here's](http://keysersblog.wordpress.com/2014/04/21/debugging-java-code-a-beginners-guide/) one I wrote for Java, which is somewhat applicable. As others have mentioned you'll find your stack trace in the _logcat_. Doing this will at least help you dig deeper into the actual issue. Most of the time, you've simply forgotten to initialize something. If so, it's just a matter of finding out what's null.

Comment: @keyser Agreed. NPE is one of the simplest problem to debug. As for why something is `null`, that's another question, which might be worth posting on SO after debugging.

Comment: Where do you initialize `inflater`?

Comment: @Joffrey Exactly. Until the question becomes _"why is this null?"_ there's work to be done :p

Comment: @keyser Indeed, that's why I said *after debugging* :)

Comment: @Joffrey Yes, I know :p I was just reiterating

Answer (score 2):

You should change this

```
 ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(parentItems.get(groupPosition));
 ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);
```

With

```
   if (convertView == null) {

    LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater)_context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_list, null);
     }

  TextView mGroupText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
  mGroupText.setText(parentItems.get(groupPosition));

  CheckBox mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb);
  mCheckBox.setChecked(isExpanded);
```

Your app crashed it's because there no `CheckedTextView` in your `group_list.xml` layout file.

Comment: Thank you i have forgotten to get the context of my inflation

Answer (score 0):

You need to change these from

```
((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(parentItems.get(groupPosition));
((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);
```

to

```
 TextView txt= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
 txt.setText(parentItems.get(groupPosition));

 CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb);
 chk.setChecked(isExpanded);
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you got the exception at this line (this was hard to find in your question, by the way):

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_list, null);
```

This means your `inflater` variable might not have been initialized properly. Check that first.

---

On the other hand, you have an other problem that @PiYusHGuPtA and @SimplePlan answered: `setText()` and `setChecked()` can't be called on the inflated view directly, but on the `TextView` and the `CheckBox` (respectively) that are **contained** in your `convertView`.

To get those particular elements from your inflated view, use `convertView.findViewById()`:

```
TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
title.setText(parentItems.get(groupPosition));

CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb);
cb.setChecked(isExpanded);
```